# How to sleep a thread and then break its sleep at any random moment in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-sleep

Developing a realtime application where I have to make the thread go to  sleep as soon as I emit a message through SocketIo to the server and wait until response come from the server through SocketIo and then break the sleep of the thread.

```
 for (TruckEnquiry value : list.values()) {

                String json = "any random string";
                SocketIO.mSocket.emit("server", json);
                try {
                    sleep(5000);  // Need to break this sleep from the UI thread of Android.
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

 }
```

// Here we get the message from the server and at this point I would like to reume the thread 
    private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {

```
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                // threadArray.get(perticular_thread).resume();  // Want to implement this.
            }
        });
    }
};
```

I have more then one thread in this file and threadArray will contain all of them.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do this. If they're emitting from a working thread, then `emit` should be using a call which blocks until the response is returned.

Comment: see `HandlerThread` class

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a single Thread to sleep because Thread.sleep(int) is a static method which "puts to sleep" all Threads in the application's thread pool.

You could:

1) Get the server response in the same connection you sent the JSON data.

2) Listen for a server eventual response by setting up a TCP (or UDP) listener in your app. Then the server would make a connection to your app with the URL "device_ip:listening_port", and the app would retrieve the response.

Comment: @Zielony Thread.sleep(); is a static method, check again. It stops the currently executing thread

Comment: It stops the thread that calls it.  Other threads are unaffected except in that calling sleep() will free up a core and so allow another ready thread to become running.